# protobuf-net backward compatibility

Tags: .net, protobuf-net

Let's say I have this class:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class OldClass
{
   [ProtoMember(1)] int X;
   [ProtoMember(2)] int Y;
   [ProtoMember(2)] int Z;
}
```

If I change OldClass to:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class NewClass
{
   Container container;
   [ProtoMember(2)] int Z;
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Container
{
   [ProtoMember(1)] int X;
   [ProtoMember(2)] int Y;
}
```

Is there a way to deserialize OldClass into NewClass?
Basically I'd like to move some members around, creating some container subclasses that will hold them, but I have lot of OldClass classes already serialized and stored on disk, and would like to be able to load them.

These X,Y,Z members aren't always primitive types like int.

Answer (score 1):

The serialized `OldClass` data only contains two values, either `X` and `Z` or `X` and `Y` because you are using the same member index for two different fields.

Assuming you did not have this problem, you could just keep `OldClass` around, deserialize to `OldClass`, and then have a constructor on `NewClass` which accepts an `OldClass`. ProtoBuf does not need to know about it.

Comment: What to do if I have serialized several OldClass as well as NewClass instances to different files, and now need to deserialize to NewClass? Just add `try{DeserializeToNewClass()}catch(WrongClassException){DeserializeToOldClass(); ConvertOldToNew();}` block?

Comment: Not sure there's a better option.

Comment: In the future you should write file headers with version information that will let you know what the serialized data in the file really is.